# How to submit a page with out page load and get back a value from a PHP variable

Tags: php, ajax

I want to implement a sort (by name) function in my php web page. I know it's in simple Php. by submitting the page and take the request value and querying according to that value.
But I want to sort without red=refreshing the page. So I have studied about jquery and Ajax, in both of them there is no way to get the request value (i.e., sort=name). How I get that request value.

I am in serious situation. Please give me a way

Answer (score 0):

If it's a table, you could use a plugin like [datatables](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html) which does that (and much more by the way)

Answer (score 0):

There IS a way to get URI query variables. I think you should use jQuery to do this as you will get the best results.

A query would look like:

```
$.get("ajaxtable.php", { sort: "name" },
   function(data){
     $('#tablecontainer').html(data);
   }
);
```

What you need is a PHP script which generates just the table for you. Then you would attach the header links to javascript functions which make a query to your PHP script, and set the contents of the area the table belongs to the new table HTML which is sorted.

Alternatively, you could use javascript tables, whereby all information is loaded into the table and allows the client to sort using javascript. Look at http://datatables.net/ (jQuery datatables) for that.

Comment: But how i get the form value in the same page. so that i can fetch the date from database.eg: if sort=name then will sort based on the name . Plesae help me